# mongoid query rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

brand new to MongoDB / mongoid and still pretty green on ruby / rails

on the rails console:

```
t = Task.all(:conditions  => {:title => "task2"})

=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
selector: {:title=>"task2"},
options:  {},
class:    Task,
embedded: false>


>> t.first
=> #<Task _id: 4d7e2cdb73ec3227dd000009, title: "task2", latitude: 23.987904829, longitude: -12.9423875,  created_by: "4d792d6973ec3248e3000001">
```

returns what I would expect, but

```
t = Task.where(:created_by => "4d792d6973ec3248e3000001")

=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
selector: {:created_by=>BSON::ObjectId('4d792d6973ec3248e3000001')},
options:  {},
class:    Task,
embedded: false>

>> t.first 
=> nil
```

same result with:

```
t = Task.all(:conditions  => {:created_by => "4d792d6973ec3248e3000001"})
```

here is the model:

```
class Task
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title
  field :latitude,                  :type => Float
  field :longitude,                 :type => Float
  field :created_by
end
```

what am I doing wrong ?

updated example:

```
>> Task.new(:title => "task8", :created_by => "4d792d6973ec3248e3000001")
=> #<Task _id: 4d81037973ec32cc22000003, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, title: "task8", created_by: "4d792d6973ec3248e3000001">

>> t = Task.all(:conditions  => {:created_by => "4d792d6973ec3248e3000001"})
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
selector: {:created_by=>BSON::ObjectId('4d792d6973ec3248e3000001')},
options:  {},
class:    Task,
embedded: false>

>> t.first 
=> nil
```

do I need to specifically define created_by as :type => String  ?

Comment: Im trying to perform a query based on the created_by field. Not sure what im doing wrong.

Comment: You're probably fighting an issue with ObjectIds and matching. What do the mongoid docs say about matching ObjectIds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like created_by is stored as a string in your document, but then you query looking for an ObjectId. ObjectId's and strings aren't the same.

Try changing

```
>> Task.new(:title => "task8", :created_by => "4d792d6973ec3248e3000001")
```

to

```
>> Task.new(:title => "task8", :created_by => BSON::ObjectId("4d792d6973ec3248e3000001"))
```

Comment: updated with new example.. do I need to specifically set type ?

Comment: did not specifically set type, so looks like mongo was "assuming" I meant object ID. wound up creating a reference association to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include this functionality in mongoid as explained in [docs](http://mongoid.org/docs/extras.html):

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
end
```